# Asp.Net Core Swagger / FromForm Comments In FromForm not display

Tags: c#, swagger

I have a controller method that looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
        /// this message it works
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fromForm">from Form text</param>
        /// <param name="fromQuery">from query text</param>
        /// <returns>return text</returns>
        [HttpGet("demo")]
        public string Demo(
            [FromForm] string fromForm,
            [FromQuery] string fromQuery)
        {
            return "Message demo";
        }
```

I use swagger from [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)
This is my output in swagger.json, you can see dont display the description value

```js
{
    '/api/demo/': {
        'get': {
            'tags': [
                'Demo'
            ],
            'summary': 'this message it works',
            'parameters': [
                {
                    'name': 'fromQuery',
                    'in': 'query',
                    'description': 'from query text',
                    'schema': {
                      'type': 'string'
                    }
                }
            ],
            'requestBody': {
                'content': {
                    'multipart/form-data': {
                        'schema': {
                            'type': 'object',
                                'properties': {
                                'fromForm': {
                                    'type': 'string'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        'encoding': {
                            'fromForm': {
                                'style': 'form'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: [FromQuery] description it works ok the message from label/// text but FromFrom dont display the description

Comment: Why aren't you using Swashbuckle? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio Then you don't need to bother with making your own swagger.json. it's all automated.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

This happends after updgrade into versions **6.0.0** to **6.0.7**,
so i go back to version **5.6.3** and works perfectly